# grep from a text file of keywords?

Tags: linux

Is it possible to use grep with a text file of keywords?

For example instead of grep -r "keyword" directory/
Something like grep -r keywordList.txt includes/

where keywordList.txt is full of a bunch of keywords?

Comment: You're right... done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [fgrep](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=fgrep).

```
fgrep -rf keywords.list includes/
```

`keywords.list` must be one keyword per line, with no extra whitespace and no regular expressions.

Comment: worked perfectly

Comment: On most systems fgrep just maps directly to "grep -F".  Depending on your work flow, knowing that may be more useful in the long run.